# Python lambda to pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have this Python code written in `pandas`, I need to write the same in `Pyspark`:

```
Source_df_write['default_flag1']=Source_df_write.apply(lambda x: 'T' if ((x['A']==1) or (x['crr'] in ('sss','tttt')) or (x['reg']=='T')) else 'F', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `when` and `otherwise`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

Source_df_write.withColumn("default_flag1", F.when(
    (F.col("A") == 1) | (F.col("crr").isin(["sss","tttt"])) | (F.col("reg") == 'T'), "T"
).otherwise("F"))
```

Comment: Value Error : cannot convert column into bool : please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.

Comment: I already using | like your answer

Comment: in my original answer, I incorrectly wrote `(F.col("crr") in ["sss","tttt"])` but it should be `(F.col("crr").isin(["sss","tttt"]))`. did you make this change?